# Error &H8000FFFF(-2147418113) when applying locked property to listbox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, listbox

I am writting an application for VBA. It results that I have a Combo Box that among other things when it changes it unlocks a listbox inside a userform called Cotizaciones_y_obras:

```
Cotizaciones_y_obras.ListBox3.Locked = False
```

The problem is when I run the VBA app and the sentence above is executed the Error &H8000FFFF(-2147418113) appears along another 6 error messages and Excel does not allow to save anything. I have to restart Excel everytime it happens.

I have reviewed some forums where people recommend you to disable all add-ons you have. I don't have any of them enabled and also it seems that the problem is for Excel 2k10 and Excel 2013.

It seems that it has to do with multipages in userforms and some properties. This person had a similar issue
[in this post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/error-2147418113-8000ffff.3759061/) .
The routine that is triggered when the Combo Box changes is the following:

```
 Private Sub Estatus_Combo_box_Change()
      With Sheets("Contadores_Folios").Range("B2")
      If Sheets("Banderas Sistema").Range("A2").Value <> "E" Then
         Folio_Cotizacion.Text = IIf(Estatus_Combo_box.Text = "Esperando        Aprobacion", "CO" + CStr(.[B2] + 1), "")
         Folio_Obra.Text = IIf(Estatus_Combo_box.Text = "Esperando Aprobacion", "", "OB" + CStr(.[C2] + 1))
      End If
 End With

  call bloquear_lista_se
  Cotizaciones_y_obras.ListBox3.Locked = False

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any multipage... ??

You could simplify the code to make debugging somewhat easier to do:

```
Private Sub Estatus_Combo_box_Change()
 With Sheets("Contadores_Folios").Range("B2").Value
  If Sheets("Banderas Sistema").Range("A2").Value <> "E" Then
   Folio_Cotizacion.Text = IIf(Estatus_Combo_box.Text = "Esperando Aprobacion", "CO" + CStr(.[B2] + 1), "")
   Folio_Obra.Text = IIf(Estatus_Combo_box.Text = "Esperando Aprobacion", "", "OB" + CStr(.[C2] + 1))
  End If
 End With

 bloquear_lista_se
 ListBox3.Locked = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip about shortening the code. 
The problem about the multipage thing is that I created all the visual objects using the vba toolbox so there is no code for such.

Comment: I assume the combobox 'estatus_combo' is in the same userform as 'Listbox3'.

Comment: Yes, it is In the same userform

Comment: If no error occurs before 'bloquear_lista_se' I'd suggest you post the code in that sub.